# Regular Expression for Expression Calculator involving Floating Point Numbers

Tags: java, android, regex

I am making an expression calculator in Android so i wanted to check whether the string qualifies as a valid expression before actually computing the answer.

I tried this regex in Java:

**^\s*([-+]?)(\d+)(?:\s*([-+*/])\s*((?:\s[-+])?\d+)\s*)+$**

But the problem with it is that, it can only match expressions which don't involve floating point numbers.

Can somebody guide me and provide me a proper regex for the same?

**Some example strings it should match:**

> 3.2+4.6-9.001*1
>
> 4+2+9.0-89
>
> 590 + 9.077236 + 3673.126 + 34787.3284 - 0.99347 * 872367

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise not doing it as a regular expression.  Can you honestly tell me you can read and debug that string?  If you wanted to add features like exponentiation, could you alter it and be confident in it?  Of course not. 
 Use a real parser framework (a tokenizer is even part of the SDK) and do validation over the token string.  You'll need to do that to effectively evaluate the expression anyway.

Comment: No i don't want exponentiation and stuff. I don't know much about parser frameworks. @Gabe-Sechan Would be good if you help me with regex itself.

Comment: It's the wrong tool. You need to get out of the regex rabbit hole and do it the right way. The short cut will cost you more time than it takes to learn the right way, and is more likely to be buggy

Comment: Teach me master

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is not suited for parsing a mathematical expression, this is because a regular expression is a language which corresponds to a DFA/NFA state machine where the language does not maintain how it reached a particular state. A context free language should instead be used to parse a mathematical expression.

In a context free language allows a parser to maintain information about how it entered the state during parsing, since a mathematical expression has a recursive tree-like structure, a context free language will also allow you to express operator precedence and check for matching brackets (which a regex cannot).

For creating a parser you can either write one yourself by hand in the form of a recursive decent parser (there are many examples of how to write one for parsing expressions), or use a tool or a framework to generate the parser for you.

You can still make use of regular expressions in order to recognise numbers and operators which you can then feed to your parser, which makes the parsing process simpler. The phase of recognising the "words" of a language is called lexical analysis and the phase of recognising the structure of the language is the syntactical phase.

This is a very brief description of parsing but I hope it helps.